# Is it a good practice to comment a block of code which might come useful in future?

Tags: svn, version-control

Is it a good practice to comment a block of code which might come useful in the future?

1. I have a snippet of code say a Java Method in my enterprise application which might help me in the near or far future.
2. I am commenting out this Method since this is not useful for now in my current build.
3. Here I have a good versioning system also like SVN.

So **what's the good practice** - to *use SubVersion* or just *comment the block* of code and use it when required?

Answer (score 5):

Commented code has a tendency to live for months and years without ever being uncommented.  It also inadvertently shows up in searches, and can misdirect others who happen to glance at it.

Assuming you are using a source code control system and a bug tracker, remove the code and put in a "task" or "bug" to re-implement the feature.

I'm not joking.  Remove it.  I've even seen bugs where comments stepped on comments and due to the nesting some of the code became uncommented!

Best practice is to rely on subversion or git or some other source code control system.  Commenting code is like attaching a sticky note to every piece of paper you should disregard sitting on your desk (instead of removing it from your desk).  Eventually the desk gets too full of papers of no importance.  Your source code is too valuable to be littered with code of no importance.

Comment: @VijaySarin You are welcome.  Often by the time such a task is started, the code around the comment has changed too much for the commented out block to be exactly right anyway.  And if it was right in the first place, it wouldn't be commented.

Answer (score 4):

(I think this question is better to be discussed under the Programmers page anyway)

Honestly, it depends.  If you know some piece of code is **really going to be useful SOON** and it is not trivial to write in the future, I see no reason that you should not keep it.  However, the key point is that you should have **sufficient comment** to let other people know why there is a piece of code snippet commented out and left in source code.

My suggestion is, when in doubt, don't keep it.  Only keep such kind of code when you know you really should do.

Comment: yeah... I also thought it to add this in  Programmers page but then got confused because of the topic.

Answer (score 1):

I would not keep this code commented, but remove it.

- Commented code will bit rot and you won't notice that it does not work any more until you remove the comment and give it a try.
- Other developers might wounder why there is your commented code. Was it commented for testing and was forgotten to un-comment? Should it be removed?
- I would use Subversion et al. You can mention that you remove the method. Then you can easily find the commit and get the code from there.